# Android PDF closes immediately after opening from Internal storage

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, android-intent

Im trying to access a pdf file after downloading it from the server and storing it in internal storage. The problem is after successfully downloading the file it opens for a split second then closes immediately. Please can someone tell me whats the proper way to do it. Thank you in advance.

Here's my code for downloading my pdf file:

> File file = new File(getFilesDir(),"pdfFolder");
>     if(!file.isDirectory()) file.mkdirs();
>   File outputFile = new File(file,
>   "samples.pdf");
>   //URLConnection....
>   //InputStream....
>   FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

Here's my code for viewing my pdf file:

> File pdfFile = new File(getFilesDir(),"/pdfFolder/samples.pdf");
>                   Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
>                     pdfIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdfFile),"application/pdf");
>                   pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
>   startActivity(pdfIntent);

Note : the absolute path points to this "/data/user/0/com.package.name/pdfFolder/sample.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
 pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

instead of

```
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

It worked for me.