# Android external PDF rendering closes immediately

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to externally render a PDF from my Android app.
My code looks like this

```
val file = File(<path-to-pdf>)
val target = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf")
target.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
val intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open With")
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
try {
      context.startActivity(intent)
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
      Log.e(e.message)
}
```

Whenever this runs on certain devices (so far observed on Pixel 2), the external reader launches, and closes immediately.
Solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788650/android-pdf-closes-immediately-after-opening-from-internal-storage) did not work.

Comment: Other apps cannot access file: uris in your app. That restriction was added in Android 7.0. Consider e.g. a FileProvider instead. https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html

Comment: It does work on some phones though. Is it possible that an issue of this sort would only occur on some devices?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work on some devices that use the default `Drive PDF Viewer`. Try alternative PDF viewers using the app picker.